# Load methods and classes from build bath in Java

Tags: java, reflection, properties, config

I am using Eclipse and I have got two libraries included in my project, foo.jar and bar.jar. In both JARs there is a class FooBar.java that includes the method getFoobar(Object xy).

Now I would like to load the method getFoobar(Object xy) either from foo.jar or from bar.jar on the basis of a properties file:

config.properties:
choice=foo

If choice==foo then the method of Foo.jar shall be picked, elsewise the method getFoobar(Object xy) from Bar.java. To make things more complicated the method getFoobar(Object xy) has in its method declaration objects loaded from another JAR which is included in foo.jar (and bar.jar respectively).

So my question is. How can I get the methods of the JARs respectively by Reflections? I have not yet found a solution. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Thank you.

Emrah

Comment: why do you are trying it by refelction. Try by check object using InstanceOf operator or use factory pattern and invoke appropriate method

Answer (score 0):

You can only load one or the other methods without getting complicated with class loaders.  A simple workaround is to rename the package of one or both libraries with [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/)  This allows you to have everything in foo.jar start with `foo.` and everything is bar.jar start with `bar.` and this avoids any confusion.  I have seen this used to be able to load several version of Xerces based on configuration (and use them concurrently in the same app)

Comment: Well, I thought as much that this would be a non-trivial problem... @Damodar: The InstanceOf-operator does not make any sense because there is a complication with the loading of the class Foobar.java. As Peter says one can only load it from ONE library. That's why I have asked..

Answer (score 0):

Write your ClassLoader that reads the property. Alternatively, you can use -D option in the jvm arguments

```
-Dchoice=foo
```

and in the code that loads the class from foo.jar or from bar.jar you can switch on this property value:

```
String choice = System.getProperty("choice");
if (Main.CHOICE_FOO.equalsIgnoreCase(choice)) {...}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

OSGI can give you a similar capability.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the methods of the JARs respectively by Reflections?

You can't.

Reflection does not allow you to select between the two versions of the class.  In fact, as far as the JVM is concerned, there is only one version; i.e. the one that appears earliest on the classpath.

You can solve this problem by defining multiple classloaders, each with a different classpath.  However, there are complications:

- If you manage to load *both* versions of the class into a running application, you will find that instances of the respective classes have different types, and you won't be able to convince the JVM otherwise.
- When your application loads another class that statically depends on one of these classes, it will bind to the version of the class that is on the classpath of the dependent classes classloader.  And you can't change that.  So, uses of the class name in declarations / typecasts / etc in the dependent class will refer to the version of the class found by the dependent classes classloader, not the other one.

The upshot is that you can't use these same-named classes like regular classes ... especially if both versions need to be loaded in the same JVM.  It is a better idea to give the two versions of the class different names.  You don't gain anything by making the class names the same.